# Why does the compiler treat std::array of different sizes as different types?

Tags: c++11

Why does the compiler treat std::array of different sizes as different types?

Comment: Because they are? Why is that a problem? If you need to accept different sized arrays you probably want `std::vector` anyway

Comment: I don't have any problem with that. I am just reading about the std::array and all articles point that the std::array of different sizes are different types but they don't provide the reason. why?

Comment: Because the C++11 and C++14 standards specify that. See [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). Explaining C++ is impossible in a few paragraphs, so please read in more details a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book, some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site, and later dive into your C++ standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template's arguments become part of the instantiated template's type. A `vector< int >` is different from a `vector< string >`. By the same logic, an `array< int, 15 >` is different from an `array< int, 30 >`. That's just how the language works.

Counterquestion. How would you handle, say, an assignment (`operator=()`), or a [`swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/swap) between those two types, `array< int, 15 >` and `array< int, 30 >`? If they are the same type, you should be able to do these operations on them, right? So... how? Without compromising the whole concept of `std::array<>` as a fixed-size container?

Comment: Understood. Yes, it is not possible to do the swap or operator= between std::array of different sizes. Thanks @DevSolar